# Как отредактировать footer в opencart?

Tags: html, opencart

Всем привет, мне тут попался ИМ на opencat где используют JOURNAL. Ну дак вот мне нужно внести изменения в код подвала (footer), по пути catalog/view/theme/journal2/template/common/footer.twig.
Вот если все от туда удалить не чего не происходит)) Открывал в разных браузерах и кеш чистил не чего не помогает, может файл другой? подскажите пожалуйста кто сталкивался.

Comment: Кэш чистил через админку opencart или у себя в браузере?

Comment: Да и в админке, и в браузере, и браузеры разные пробовал, изменений не каких, но если прописать .footer {display:none;} то подвал выключается, остальные файлы без проблем редактируются вот только footer